# Vuetify: v-pagination: howto change truncation behavior of visible elements

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

i'm researching some strange behavior of `v-pagination` element. The thing is in position of `v-pagination__more` placeholder.

On my project, where i'm using `v-pagination` - the placeholder with `...` is positioned directly in center of visible elements and this behavior is unwanted in my project's requirements. Much more- it differs from behavior of example from official documentation of `v-pagination`. Please take a look at the example below:
how it looks on my page: < 1 2 3 ... 18 19 20 >
how it looks on vuetify's plaground page: <1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 20 >

i'm using on project these versions:

```
"vue": "^3.4.15",   
"vuetify": "^3.5.2",   
"vuex": "^4.0.2"
```

example of template's usage on my project:
`<v-pagination v-model="page" :length="20" :total-visible="7"></v-pagination>`

here is link to vuetify's [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpNjsEKgkAURX/l8VYFqWVJIJPQd2SLSV82MI7D+JRA/PdGw3J3z1nce28Dtq6IrtaGfUeYomCqrZZMWW4ARB9YWSkjWTUG+qBuStKXHL2kHCHVZCp+eRHvJ+SGpQ561aqHJm/POWYiWnf4VhGtJjy2hVOW5zl628YxlPSUnWYYJgdQSpab7UIAjrhz5s8A050UDrvFjN8wzsKDiH4jOO7wGJ7CQ4JTSMIY7x+PxFIT) with the same setup

didn't found anything useful on [documentation page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/) or on api's [page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-pagination/#links), neither on other resources.
i need to fix positioning of ellipsys placeholder to the end of visible elements as it is on official documentations page

will be grateful for any ideas.
cheers

Comment: Pagination in Vuetify 3 cannot produce a sequence like this, but Vuetify 2 can. Compare [code of v3](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/d1251f50f2d85b34c06c65895bd2d2b82bdd412e/packages/vuetify/src/components/VPagination/VPagination.tsx#L205-L215) with [code of v2](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/2127ff1fb332700f4e1a2e4a41843162217f5bb3/packages/vuetify/src/components/VPagination/VPagination.ts#L128-L132). So I would guess that you are looking at output from Vuetify 2. Is that possible?

Comment: yepp, you're right. on my case the version of vuetify was still 2X, though package.json was updated and project was rebuilded (internal project architecture obstacles). so thank you very mych, you've leaded me to the right way